# Ionic Angular app going to login screen on click of back button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am developing an ionic app with Angular and facing one issue related to android device back button.

when I am installing app from android studio and on using back button app minimize function (cordova-plugin-appminimize) is working fine and able to reload the application with no issues.

but when I am installing by sharing apk and on click of back button app is getting minimized and after reloading app is navigating to login screen.

Please let me know if you have faced any similar issue and what was the resolution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a Routing guard(canActivate) to prevent this.
or
You can also handle the back button event

[see back button handling in ionic](https://medium.com/@holudare2076/ionic-4-hardware-back-button-event-2a6b51fa9c44)

Comment: Hi Sanjay- Thanks for the response. I am already using Routing guard(canActivate) and it's working fine, only issue is when I am installing by sharing apk.

Comment: are you storing your data in cookies?